# playwright/xpath - How to get next element in dynamicaly list

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, xpath, playwright

I'm out of ideas. I try get for example genere from this code. List items are generated dynamicaly if item has no information about something then section does not exist. I tring to find div with text "genere" and try to get text from next in h3 element. I use JS, Playwright, XPath. Example code:

```
<div class="infoItem">
    <h3 class="header">director</h3>
    <div class="info">John Doe</div>
    <h3 class="header">country</h3>
    <div class="info">DE</div>
    <h3 class="header">screenwriting</h3>
    <div class="info">John Doe</div>

    <!--[...]-->
    
    <h3 class="header">genere</h3>
    <div class="info">Comedy</div>
    <h3 class="header">premiere</h3>
    <div class="info">2019-02-18</div>
 </div>
```

Comment: there are 5 h3 tags with class `header`, I am not sure about `playwright`. But I can give you an idea that retrieve all h3 with class header with this xpath `//h3[@class='header']` and then iterate over the list with a condition that if it has `genere` or not.

Comment: I can’t see any div element which contains text as genere? Genere text is there with h3 element. Please post a valid html and provide your expected out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the h3 element below the `genere` text by using what playwright calls the [selecting elements based on layout](https://playwright.dev/docs/other-locators#css-matching-elements-based-on-layout)

```js
page.locator('h3:below(:text("genere"))') //gets <h3 class="header">premiere</h3>
```